# Getting asp:SqlDataSource Connection String dynamically from a method (Without Webconfig)

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

Trying to set sql server from a class in asp:sqldatasource tag:

```
Public static SqlConnection getConnection()
{
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
      //rest of the code that 100% works
      return conn;
}
```

This function is tested in C# code and it works 100%.
Now I'm trying to use it in an asp:SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlDBConnection"
ConnectionString="<%# inProcessInventory.DataTools.getConnection().ConnectionString %>"
```

I receive:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit: https://forums.asp.net/t/1072016.aspx?Dynamic+connection+strings

> If your connection string is created dynamically at run time. We
> cannot set the connection string at design time.

Binding to the property might not work since this depends on when you call DataBind on your controls.

In this case, it's better to set this in code behind event handler for Page_Load like

```
Me.dsTest.ConnectionString = objClientConnection.ConnectionString
```

Then you can call DataBind() manually.

Answer (score 2):

A ConnectionString is, as the name implies, a string. You are returning a `SqlConnection` where a string is expected.

```
public static string getConnection()
{
    return "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=yourDB;User ID=yourUser;Password=pa$$w0rd";
}
```

Or

```
public static SqlConnection getConnection()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=yourDB;User ID=yourUser;Password=pa$$w0rd");
    return conn;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It does work correctly if you set the connection string in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlDBConnection.ConnectionString = inProcessInventory.DataTools.getConnection().ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: I'm returning SqlConnection.ConnectionString

Comment: No because there isn't any. At least not in your snippet. But i've updated my answer to inlcude a return with `SqlConnection`.

Comment: thanks. the functions is fetching connection string parts from properties parts. it works I can assure you. The syntax of asp:SqlConnection has an issue

Answer (score 0):

We often use SqlConnection and set Connectionstring directly or Call from configurationManager(in Asp.net). Do you know about SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class. It is under namespace System.Data.SqlClient .

You can use this class to set Connectionstring values in SqlConnection Class. Here is the code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new  SqlConnection();

SqlConnectionStringBuilder myBuilder = new  SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

myBuilder.UserID = "sa";

myBuilder.Password = "sa123";

myBuilder.InitialCatalog = "DbName";

myBuilder.DataSource = "ServerName";

myBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;

myConnection.ConnectionString = myBuilder.ConnectionString;
```